# Can the top off a coke can serve as a heat-sink?

Tags: heatsink

Looking around here for a heat-sink for a TO-18 (2n2222) form I don't quite see one around that will serve. The thought in my mind is whether I may cut the top off the Coke Can, and use it as a sink; punch a hole the size of the TO-18, cut tabs along the perimeter of the cap, and stick the transistor in it.

Will the aluminum from a coke/beer can serve as a heat sink?

Comment: Not much heat capacity in the thin metal of a can. However, several layers of it, tightly bolted at the heat sink tab, could help you get by for trying it out. Also, the thin metal could then be shaped with a pair of pliers, for a good set of heat radiating fins!

Comment: Sure it will work to a degree.  But there is a real concern with how thin it is - heat conductivity is a function of cross section.  Also the coatings - some sort of plastic on the inside, and paint on the outside.  The coatings could also limit the effectiveness of stacking multiple layers.  That said, the *top* of a can is likely a bit thicker than the sides, and isn't usually painted so it does seem like the best part to use.  Using the outside to contact the part would seem best, so the inside coating will be on the larger dissipating area rather than on the smaller junction area.

Comment: How about a copper (pre-1982) penny? Drill a hole in a couple pennies that allows a tight fit with the TO-18 case, and slide them on with a bit of heatsink paste, leaving an air-gap between them?

Comment: @Johnny: Very good call! Only it won't work in my geography; no copper coins here in atleast the last 40 years. But it makes me wonder about a copper gasket, or even the brass jet into a carburetter - if one can be found

Comment: @Johnny a couple of pennies fanned out might work, but you are trading physical space for the effort. Tangent did a comparison between a paper clip, a penny (in different formations), and actual heatsink, and four pennies http://tangentsoft.net/elec/diy-hs.html

Comment: @Everyone: Yeah, sorry, didn't even look to see where you were living before I made that suggestion. :) If you check with someone who just returned from the USA, they probably have some pennies in their pocket. The all-copper pre-1982 ones are getting harder to find but they are still out there

Comment: @Passerby: You could always trim back the pennies if they are too big  (or just use one instead of 2 if you don't need to sink as much heat), the commercial TO-18 heatsink pictured below is not too much smaller than a penny - a penny's diameter is 19mm compared to 12.7mm for that commercial heatsink

Comment: @Johnny one penny was worse than a **paperclip**. He needed four fanned out pennies to match a regular heatsink's capability. By cutting them, or using less, you are negating any of the actual benefit of them.

Comment: @Passerby - The TO-220 style heatsink that you linked to is designed for devices that need greater heat dissipation than the TO-18 since the TO-220 has has a metal tab with a screw for better bonding to the heatsink. Take a look at the commercial TO-18 heatsink that Oli Glaser links to below - smaller in diameter than a penny (but better heat transfer from the TO-18 case since the heat sink wraps around the entire case).

Comment: @Everyone Since you are in India, TO-18 aluminium split-ring type heat sinks are available at Lamington Road, Mumbai for INR 8 each. TO-18 heat sinks with 8 fins are around INR 24 each.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh: Ty; I'll try L Road when next in 'Bay (+: be fun to do one of these home-brew sinks though. Good recommendations all around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you can get good thermal and mechanical contact I don't see why it can't work. I think this version used a bit of heat shrink to hold it nice and tight.

[image]

Comment: Erm. Just corrected the form from TO-92 to TO-18

Comment: same answer applies - good thermal and mechanical contact and of course a good radiating area

Answer (score 1):

Any metal will be better than nothing at all, and depending on size and shape will be more/less effective. There is no reason a coke can lid correctly shaped won't serve as a heatsink. Make sure you connect the surfaces (heatsink/transistor) together well, you can use a dab of thermal compound if you have some.

Forced air cooling is also worth considering if you have a few components you need to keep cool.

For reference/info, TO-18 heatsinks do exist (although they are not so common):

[Example](http://uk.farnell.com/aavid-thermalloy/322400b00000g/heat-sink-100k-w-to-18/dp/2295717) - see [this page](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1699367.pdf) for dimensions and thermal details.

[image]

Comment: They are available; just a wee bit prohibitively expensive for an amateur being priced at ~INR 94.00/each. http://in.element14.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp;jsessionid=4XNYZ25TSNQHACWNBBSRFWI?N=203168&Ntk=gensearch&Ntt=TO-18&Ntx=mode+matchallpartial&displaytext=&hasOnlySelectedPGRefinement=false&getResults=true&_requestid=41751

Comment: It is cheaper to buy a transistor in TO-220 package and not use a heatsink than to use one of these heatsinks. Rth j-c of 2N2222 in TO-18 is 146K/W!

Comment: Yes, good point, I agree - the link was just for info purposes and a reference design. If at all possible I would avoid the TO-18 package and use TO-220 as you mention, or another more common package - the thermal properties are better and heatsinks are readily available cheaply if needed.